# django change password - django-parsley

Tags: python, django, validation, change-password

I hate being a noob.

I have implemented the django [change password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords) - out of the box and it is working as expected.

I wanted to apply client side validation with [django-parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley).

To add [django-parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley), I must add an import in the forms.py file that has the change password form and then append the forms with @parsleyfy, like so:

```
from parsley.decorators import parsleyfy

@parsleyfy
```

But being a noob, I cannot locate a forms.py file that has the change password form data.

Can I apply django-parsley to the change password template?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create password change form and apply `parslefy`

```
from parsley.decorators import parsleyfy
@parsleyfy

class ChangePasswordForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','password')
```

And in your views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = User.objects.get(email = request.POST['email'])
    user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
    user.save()
```

Comment: What you mean by it's not working ,? I have my project working with parslefy. Tell How you implement your `changepassword` ?. Or Did you seen the HTML view source about the parsleyfy html render tags , Anything ?. You simply tell `does not work` will not help you. you have to more specific.